# postgresql set timezone for materialized view

Tags: postgresql

ok - we've found a bug in one of our systems with materialized views refreshing to different data, depending on which system called the refresh.

It turned out to be a problem with the client date settings - it depends on the timezone of the user.

This is a big risk.  I know *per field* we can override settings - but it's tricky - because views consume other views, and date conversions/calculations are happpening anywhere in the view hierarchy - so there's no way we can guarantee client specific calculations won't get through.

Is there any way we can embed something in the view definition that sets the current time zone for the whole view - so it doesn't matter who does the refresh, it will always produce the same result?

I tried this - but it doesn't work :( - but want something like this:

```sql
create materialized view blah as (
set timezone to 'Australia/Brisbane';
select now())
```

Comment: Are the field types for the timestamps in the views `timestamp` or `timestamptz`?

Comment: that's the thing - we are talking hundreds of fields over hundreds of tables with a large hierarchy of views on top of views on top of views - including literally every combination of date/timestamp type.   Also I have no control over the tables or table structures - they all exist already - so I'm need to fix the problem for new views.  At the moment I'm hardwiring the above set timezone thing everywhere the views are called in code... and that works... but someone will forget.

Comment: Well you can't do what you show above. Is it not possible to set the server timezone to 'Australia/Brisbane' globally?

Comment: but that's the entire point - it depends on the _client's_ timezone - not on the server - if it used the server timezone there would be no problem.  The problem comes because when different people run the "refresh view" command we get different values in the table

Comment: I'm not following. If everybody is working on the same server then the time zone being used will be whatever the `show timezone` returns. The caveat being that it is possible for people/clients to issue a `SET time zone ...` or equivalent to change it for session. Is that what is happening?

Comment: A [example] demonstrating the issue would be interesting...

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Any client driver worth its salt will set `timezone` to the client's time zone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you code your materialized view to depend on the current setting of database parameters, you are in trouble, because many of them can be changed on the session level. Don't do that.

In the current case, avoid anything that casts `date` or `timestamp without timezone` to `timestamp with time zone` or vice versa, because `timezone` will clandestinely enter into any such conversions.

Always specify the time zone explicitly:

- to convert from `date` or `timestamp` to `timestamp with time zone`, use

  ```
  current_date AT TIME ZONE 'whatever'
  ```
- to convert from `timestamp with time zone` to `date` or `timestamp`, use

  ```
  current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'whatever'
  ```

Both operators are called `AT TIME ZONE`, but they are different.

I see that your problem is that there is a large body of pre-existing view definitions that do not adhere to this principle. Perhaps you can get away with something like:

```
WITH setzone AS (
   SELECT set_config('timezone', 'UTC', TRUE)
)
SELECT /* your query */;
```

But you need to change the query so that it references `setzone` somewhere in the query (you could `CROSS JOIN` it), so that it is executed.

Comment: that with block seems exactly what I was looking for if it works - thanks heaps!

Comment: omg - it worked -  thanks!!!

  with setzone as (
        select set_config('timezone', 'Australia/Brisbane',TRUE), now() as refreshed_at
    )
    select refreshed_at, ...